# Is there a phrasal verb that has an opposite meaning to a phrasal verb 'filter out ? '

Tags: phrases

I have a question about a phrasal verb `filter out`. So, according to Oxford Learner's Dictionaries it means to remove something that you don't want.

Is there a phrasal verb that  means removing/selecting only something that I do want?
For example:

*This web app  makes it easy to filter out good questions ( typically 3 upvotes or more ) within a selected period of time.*

As far as I understand, `filter out` here means that I'd like to remove good questions; however,  the intended meaning was to remove bad questions and to keep good once.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This web app makes it easy to **select/identify** good questions.

Comment: @Greybeard thanks! This works for me.

Comment: There’s also *filter for*.